# Get posts on a specific date with the Wordpress REST API

Tags: wordpress, get, wordpress-rest-api

I want to get posts on a specific date with the Wordpress REST API. But when I delete the "after" part, I get all posts.What should I do to get only posts on a given day, not before or after?  I read the documentation but there is no any example for this. 
 I also searched on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find an HTTPS method that works for me.

```
{{baseURL}}/wp/v2/posts?orderby=date&order=desc&after=2019-09-29T13:00:00
```

Edit: I found a solution as follows:

```
{{baseURL}}/wp/v2/posts?orderby=date&order=desc&before=2019-10-03T13:00:00&after=2019-10-01T13:00:00
```

Only way to get posts on a specific date is specifying the range of date.